# What is the correct way of changing mode of fopen after checking if file exists?

Tags: c

In my programm, I want to check if a logfile already exists and then write some data into it. Therefore I first opened it with mode "a". If this returned NULL, I reopend it  with "w", wrote the header and opened it with "a" again to append the data. But after some time I always got "Too many open files" as error - so obviously opening the same file to the same pointer still opens a new handle (I wasn't aware of that). But now I'm not entirely sure how to write that part of the code - do I always have to fclose and then fopen again?

```
FILE *target;       
target= fopen (ComplPath, "a");

if (target == NULL) 
{   
    //fclose(target); ?!?!
    target= fopen (ComplPath, "w");
    if (target != NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(target, "Header-Text \n");  
        fprintf(target, "Data" \n);
        fclose(target);
    }
    else  
    {
        printf("Error at writeToLog: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }  
}
else    
{
    fprintf(target, "data");
    fclose(target);
}
```

See after the first if: Do I have to close the file before reopening it with "w"? It seems quite inefficient to close and reopen a file all the time. Or is there in general some better way to do this task?

Comment: "_Do I have to close the file before reopening it with "w"?_" No. Since the file never opened and `fopen` returned `NULL`

Comment: You appear to be missing a closing curly brace `}` before the last `else`.

Comment: True, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just open the file once with the `"a"` mode, and use `ftell()` to know if that created a new file.

Contrary to what your question suggests, both `"a"` and `"w"` will create a new file if it doesn't exist. The difference is that `"w"` will truncate it to zero length if it already exists.

```
FILE *target;       
target= fopen (ComplPath, "a");
if (!target) {
    /* error out */
}
if (ftell(target) == 0) {
    /* write the header */
}
```

Comment: Another important difference between "a" and "w" mode is, that with "a", you cannot set the file position indicator before the end of the file. All writing occurs after, even if `rewind()` / `fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_SET)` is used. In "w" mode, you can write anywhere.